# OpenSearch settings value in milliseconds

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm trying to update OpenSearch's index settings field with milliseconds value.

The example that I found is in seconds.

Can someone assist me on how can I set the value in milliseconds?

```
PUT /my_index/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "30s"
    }
}
```

Comment: the default value is 1s. Why do you want such a low value?

Comment: Why would you do that? try with 0.001 and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply `ms` unit value.

Documnetaion
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/units/